# Group of users with same Firebase Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating two android apps for a local Halloween event/game. End-user app and staff app.

In the staff app, we register the team in firebase databse right before the event starts, and get credentials for the team members to login.

In the end-user app, all team members must login with the same credentials given by the staff so every device of the same team will be connected to the same team database table as just one user.

The question is: when the team gets registed by the staff can the staff give the team members a code so they quick authenticate and access their team database table?

Or would you try a different aproach?

Comment: What do you mean through "when the team gets registed by the staff"? You want the stuff to create users for the members?

Comment: @AlexMamo Exacly. Teams will gather at the starting point to sign in the team and get the "team login code" so they can access their team's interface.

Comment: And you want to store their credentials in the database?

Comment: I guess so. I want something that will login the players easily and fast. Can it be unsafe?

Comment: Will an answer be helful for you even if will doesn't store the credentials in the database?

Comment: Of course. I'm open minded :D

Comment: Have you considered using email link sign-in? You can generate the links and send them to the staff to sign in and complete registration.

Comment: So an answer that will contain an authentication process might help you, right?  Please also responde with @AlexMamo